# Unable to install Plattform IO IDE

Tags: macos, platformio

I’m constantly failing to install Platform IO IDE for Visual Studio Code or Atom. I’m working on OSX with High Sierra.

I have two users, both are Admins. The first user can install with VSC and Atom just fine. The second user always gets this error message:

> PIP: Error: spawn /Volumes/Macintosh
>   HD/Users/micha/.platformio/penv/bin/pip ENOENT

I already tried to delete the .platformio folder and start over, without success. The error shows up for Visual Studio Code and Atom.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a solution, but a suitable workaround.

I installed platformio core with homebrew, which works fine. Then I installed the IDE plugin, which seams to detect that the core is already there and does not try to instal it a second time.

I did this for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows, I tried to install platform-io vs extension to use exsting anaconda.

After setting `platformio-ide.useBuiltinPIOCore` to `false` and `platformio-ide.customPATH` to "path/to/py27", I am able to install platformio with existing python vEnv, but it ended up in an endless loop [press restart -> checking install -> please restart]

After adjusting the `customPath` to pointing to both pio.exe and python.exe residing directory, it works all right:
     `platformio-ide.customPATH`: "path/to/py27;path/to/py27/Scripts"

I think you can adjust these setting to make these two users use seperate venv, so that there won't be any permission conflict or related issues.